# How to bundle all related packages with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently struggling to bundle all `codemirror` related packages with `Webpack` into a dedicated file.

The imports in my main.js look like that:

```js
import {basicSetup, EditorView} from "codemirror";
import {java} from "@codemirror/lang-java";

new EditorView({
  doc: "console.log('aloha')\n",
  extensions: [basicSetup, java()],
  parent: document.querySelector("#cm")
});
```

According to these imports the `node_modules` folder has the following structure:

```
node_modules
+ .... @codemirror
+ .... codemirror
```

Now, what I want is to bundle all codemirror related code into one file. So what I ended up with is the following `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    filename: "./app-[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: './app-[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname)
  },

  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        codemirror: {
          // test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*[\\/]/,                    /* works */
          // test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*codemirror.*[\\/]/,        /* won't work */
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](@codemirror|codemirror)[\\/]/, /* won't work */
          name: "codemirror",
          chunks: "all"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

No matter how I try to build the `test regex` I always end up with a ***app-main.bundle.js*** which contains about 5.500 lines of code and a ***app-codemirror.bundle.js*** holding the remaining 23.000 lines.

If I simply provide a *collect it all* `.*` regex then all the code is bundled as desired, but the withdraw would be that I can't split up further for other packages.

Can someone please tell mit what's going on here and how to get a single file for all codemirror related code?